# Regex to match the specific date string

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match a date string like below:

```
string1 = '11/13/2019 - 11/13/2019' 
string2 = '11/14/2019 11/14/2019'
string3 = '01/21/2019. . 11/20/2019'
```

I am using the below code to fetch all of them:

```
match : r"(\d+[/1]\d+[/1]\d+[ - ]\d+[/1]\d+[/1]\d+)"
```

But the above is giving me only string `1`.

All strings have two dates in common, I wanted to match it with both the date formats, ignoring the characters in between them. Is there a way to do this?
ignore `'-'`, `' '`, `'. .'`

Comment: Read [converting-string-into-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345)

Comment: What is the purpose of `[/1]`? Your regex matches `111111111111 11111111111111`, not sure that's a valid date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the @GolamMazidsajib’s answer, if you want to be a bit more strict about it your regex should look like this:

```
^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}[- .]+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$
```

1. adding `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end ensures that the string contains only the date range, not `something 11/14/2019 11/14/2019 something` (unless you want it to, then just remove these)
2. `{2}` and `{4}` instead of `+` after `\d`-s will match only the specified number of digits, so that the strings like `111111/14/2019 11/14/2019` or `1/14/2019 11/14/2019` won’t be accepted
3. `+` instead of `*` after character set `[-\s\.]` will require strings to have at least one separator character between the dates; rejecting, for example, `11/14/201911/14/2019`
4. took place of `\s` to filter out strings that contain any other whitespace separators, like a new line `\n` or a tab `\t`

I also simplified it a bit:

- removed unnecessary character sets with a single slash in them: both `[/]` and `/` match just one character "/"
- removed escape of the dot `.` inside the character set `[- .]`, because inside a set it behaves like a literal and not a special character
- removed the grouping parenthesis around the whole regex, since you’d need those only if you want to extract the matched substring, which guessing from the question you don’t

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sCIe5/3).

---

Of course, we can go further (perhaps, even a bit overboard) and try to get closer to matching only the *valid* dates, with something like this:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/\d{4}[- .]+(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/\d{4}$
```

- `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` is a non-capturing group that matches either (notice `|`)

  - `0[1-9]` — `0` followed by a digit from `1` to `9`, *or*
  - `1[0-2]` — `1` followed by `0`, `1`, or `2`
    this way we require month’s number to be one of `01`, `02`, `03`, …,`12` and nothing else
- `(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` is also a non-capturing group that matches either of the three sequences:

  - `0[1-9]` — `0` followed by a digit from `1` to `9`, *or*
  - `[12]\d` — `1` or `2` followed by any digit, *or*
  - `3[01]` — `3` with either `0` or `1` after it
    here we require the day be one of `01`, `02`, `03`, …, `31` and nothing else. *Note*, that it doesn’t check if the month matches the day number, so `02/31/2020` (31th of February) will be allowed
- `\d{4}` left as is, allowing years to be from `0000` to `9999`

See the examples in another [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sCIe5/4).

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:  `(\d+[/]\d+[/]\d+[-\s\.]*\d+[/]\d+[/]\d+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/9) here

Comment: What is the purpose of `[/1]`? Your regex matches `111111111111 11111111111111`, not sure that's a valid date!

Comment: Can you look into my edited question, am facing a difficulty there

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this and this worked.

```
[r"(\d+/\d+/\d+\s-\s\d+/\d+/\d+)", r"(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+/\d+/\d+)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single regex for both format:

```
^\d+/\d+/\d+\s(?:-\s)?\d+/\d+/\d+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MdzsUA/1)

Comment: can you please answer the edited question. Am facing a difficulty there